# How to get recent uploaded files from a Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, directory

I have upload multiple files in a folder using c# but when I want to get all of the recently uploaded files ,I found all the files from that directory

```
  string Uplodefile = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Content\\Uploads\\";
  string[] S1 = Directory.GetFiles(Uplodefile);
```

how can I get recent uploaded multiple file using string[].

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get recent uploaded files by using [Directory.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-7.0#system-io-directory-getfiles(system-string)). But as per the documentation this method:

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified directory.

To get recently uploaded files from a directory, you have to enumerate files of that directory and specify a datetime by which condition you want to get your files.

On the below code snippet I use `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1)` which will give the datetime of 1 minute earlier from your current time, and find all the files which `CreationTime` is greater than that time. And then take the `FullPath` of return files and store them into an array of string.

```
string[] S1 = new DirectoryInfo(Uplodefile).EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
.Where(file => file.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1)).Select(file => file.FullName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Don't just paste code here. Try to explain to the person who asked what it does and why it will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Now wrote a detailed answer what my code snippet does and why it will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to `sort the files in descending order by creation date`. Now the newest file is in index 0, the next one is in index 1 and so on

```
 DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Content\\Uploads\\");
 FileInfo[] S1 = info.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
 string[] recentUploadedFiles= S1.Select(file => file.FullName).ToArray();
```

The second way is to say that I want get files that have been uploaded in the last 5 minutes (you can change the number 5).

```
 DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Content\\Uploads\\");
 FileInfo[] S1= info.GetFiles().Where(p => p.CreationTime > 
 DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5)).ToArray(); //DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-5) ==>means subtract 5 minutes from the present time
 string[] recentUploadedFiles= S1.Select(file => file.FullName).ToArray();
```